# is the structure "Either ... or ... or" correct?

Tags: conjunctions, correlating-conjunctions

Is it grammatically possible to have the structure "either ... or ... or" in a sentence?
For instance:

> The name can be experienced either visually or auditorily or tactilely.

Putting aside the fact that this sentence might sound awkward, Would it be grammatically correct? Is it grammatically possible? And if so, what would it be the grammatical explanation?

Comment: In my opinion, I prefer "The name can be experienced visually, auditorily, or tactilely.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether it is *grammatically* correct is, I suspect, a matter of opinion.  By definition the word "either" suggests *two* options, not *three*.

> [**either**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/either) : one or the other **of two**:

However, other dictionaries offer a more lenient definition:

> **[either](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/either)** : Used before the first of two **(or occasionally more)** given alternatives (the other being introduced by ‘or’)

Setting aside the grammatical question, the truth is that native English speakers bend these kind of rules all the time.  Your sentence is natural, although, because it contradicts the expected use of *either*, it may sound like you aren't *certain* of the choices.

I would say it's fine for casual conversation, but may create unwanted confusion if used in any formal speaking or writing.  In formal writing, remove *either*:

> The name can be experienced visually, auditorily, or tactilely.